# Json.NET duplicates enum definitions in schema

Tags: c#, json, enums, json.net

I have a comms protocol in which I'm sending multiple different object types via JSON, using a common "MessageType" field to identify them for deserialization to the correct classes. I'm using Json.NET.Schema to produce the schema from my classes that I'll then use to generate POJOs for use in an Android app I'll be communicating with.

To easily make a schema for all my objects, I have a dummy root class that has a property of each type I'll be using, so I make a schema of that and make POJOs and end up with the classes I want, plus the dummy I can ignore.

Problem I'm getting is that the enums are being defined in every class in the POJOs. So instead of a single `MessageType` enum, I end up with `Class1.MessageType`, `Class2.MessageType` etc and they're distinct types and hence (I assume!) won't be comparable in switch statements and the like. This can be seen in the schema, so it's a problem with schema generation rather than with the POJO generator.

I could probably resolve this by using numbers instead of representing the enums as strings in JSON, but the string representation makes things easy to see and less brittle should things change so I thought it worth asking on here first in case I'm doing something daft!

For reference, a part of the code containing my message objects is

```
public enum eCommandType
{
    UNKNOWN,
    PING,
    GET_TIMINGS,
    GET_EVENT_ID,
    NEW_EVENT,
    LOAD_PEOPLE,
    LOAD_TAGS,
    SET_LOCATION
}

public enum eMessageType
{
    UNKNOWN,
    COMMAND_BASE,
    COMMAND_LOADPEOPLE,
    RESPONSE_PING,
    RESPONSE_GENERAL,
    RESPONSE_TIMINGS_PEOPLE,
    RESPONSE_TIMINGS_CLICKER
}

/* A wrapper class so we can put all our classes
 * in one object for the JSON schema.
 */
public class DummyContainer
{
    public eCommandType eCommandType { get; set; }
    public eMessageType eMessageType { get; set; }
    public CommandBase CommandBase { get; set; }
    public CommandLoadPeople CommandLoadPeople { get; set; }
    public ResponsePing ResponsePing { get; set; }
    public ResponseGeneral ResponseGeneral { get; set; }
    public ResponseTimingsPeople ResponseTimingsPeople { get; set; }
    public ResponseTimingsClicker ResponseTimingsClicker { get; set; }
    public DummyMessage DummyMessage { get; set; }
}
.
. 
.
public class CommandBase : iMessage
{
    eMessageType _messageType = eMessageType.COMMAND_BASE;

    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public eCommandType CommandType { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public eMessageType MessageType { get { return _messageType;} private set {_messageType = value;} }

    public CommandBase(eCommandType CommandType)
    {
        this.CommandType = CommandType;
    }
}
```

the code that generates the schema is

```
    public static string GenerateSchema()
    {
        //Encode enums as strings, not integers.
        JSchemaGenerator stringEnumGenerator = new JSchemaGenerator();
        stringEnumGenerator.GenerationProviders.Add
            (new StringEnumGenerationProvider());

        stringEnumGenerator.ContractResolver = new ShouldSerializeContractResolver();

        JSchema schema = stringEnumGenerator.Generate(typeof(DummyContainer));
        string s = schema.ToString();

        Console.WriteLine(s);
        return s;

    }
```

where ShouldSerializeContractResolver is

```
/* Don't do anything with virtual fields- these are used for navigation properties in the 
 * entities and screw up serialization.
 */
public class ShouldSerializeContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    public new static readonly ShouldSerializeContractResolver Instance = new ShouldSerializeContractResolver();

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {

        JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        /* For some reason, MessageType is being identified as being virtual and gets dropped.
         * So we explicitly allow anything with this name.
         */
        if (member.Name == "MessageType") return property;

        bool isVirtual = property.DeclaringType.GetProperty(member.Name).GetAccessors()[0].IsVirtual;

        if (isVirtual) 
            return null;

        return property;
    }
}
```

and the schema is

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "eCommandType": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": [
        "UNKNOWN",
        "PING",
        "GET_TIMINGS",
        "GET_EVENT_ID",
        "NEW_EVENT",
        "LOAD_PEOPLE",
        "LOAD_TAGS",
        "SET_LOCATION"
      ]
    },
    "eMessageType": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": [
        "UNKNOWN",
        "COMMAND_BASE",
        "COMMAND_LOADPEOPLE",
        "RESPONSE_PING",
        "RESPONSE_GENERAL",
        "RESPONSE_TIMINGS_PEOPLE",
        "RESPONSE_TIMINGS_CLICKER"
      ]
    },
    "CommandBase": {
      "type": [
        "object",
        "null"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "CommandType": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "UNKNOWN",
            "PING",
            "GET_TIMINGS",
            "GET_EVENT_ID",
            "NEW_EVENT",
            "LOAD_PEOPLE",
            "LOAD_TAGS",
            "SET_LOCATION"
          ]
        },
        "MessageType": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "UNKNOWN",
            "COMMAND_BASE",
            "COMMAND_LOADPEOPLE",
            "RESPONSE_PING",
            "RESPONSE_GENERAL",
            "RESPONSE_TIMINGS_PEOPLE",
            "RESPONSE_TIMINGS_CLICKER"
          ]
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "CommandType",
        "MessageType"
      ]
    },
    "CommandLoadPeople": {
      "type": [
        "object",
        "null"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "People": {
          "type": [
            "array",
            "null"
          ],
          "items": {
            "type": [
              "object",
              "null"
            ],
            "properties": {
              "Id": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "Name": {
                "type": [
                  "string",
                  "null"
                ]
              },
              "DOB": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "Gender": {
                "type": [
                  "string",
                  "null"
                ]
              },
              "ContactDetails": {
                "type": [
                  "string",
                  "null"
                ]
              },
              "NOKDetails": {
                "type": [
                  "string",
                  "null"
                ]
              },
              "Notes": {
                "type": [
                  "string",
                  "null"
                ]
              }
            },
            "required": [
              "Id",
              "Name",
              "DOB",
              "Gender",
              "ContactDetails",
              "NOKDetails",
              "Notes"
            ]
          }
        },
        "CommandType": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "UNKNOWN",
            "PING",
            "GET_TIMINGS",
            "GET_EVENT_ID",
            "NEW_EVENT",
            "LOAD_PEOPLE",
            "LOAD_TAGS",
            "SET_LOCATION"
          ]
        },
        "MessageType": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "UNKNOWN",
            "COMMAND_BASE",
            "COMMAND_LOADPEOPLE",
            "RESPONSE_PING",
            "RESPONSE_GENERAL",
            "RESPONSE_TIMINGS_PEOPLE",
            "RESPONSE_TIMINGS_CLICKER"
          ]
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "People",
        "CommandType",
        "MessageType"
      ]
    },
    "ResponsePing": {
      "type": [
        "object",
        "null"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "MessageType": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "UNKNOWN",
            "COMMAND_BASE",
            "COMMAND_LOADPEOPLE",
            "RESPONSE_PING",
            "RESPONSE_GENERAL",
            "RESPONSE_TIMINGS_PEOPLE",
            "RESPONSE_TIMINGS_CLICKER"
          ]
        },
        "LastPeopleUpdate": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "LastTagsUpdate": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "EventID": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "MessageType",
        "LastPeopleUpdate",
        "LastTagsUpdate",
        "EventID"
      ]
    },
    "ResponseGeneral": {
      "type": [
        "object",
        "null"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "MessageType": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "UNKNOWN",
            "COMMAND_BASE",
            "COMMAND_LOADPEOPLE",
            "RESPONSE_PING",
            "RESPONSE_GENERAL",
            "RESPONSE_TIMINGS_PEOPLE",
            "RESPONSE_TIMINGS_CLICKER"
          ]
        },
        "ErrorMessage": {
          "type": [
            "string",
            "null"
          ]
        },
        "Result": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "MessageType",
        "ErrorMessage",
        "Result"
      ]
    },
    "ResponseTimingsPeople": {
      "type": [
        "object",
        "null"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "MessageType": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "UNKNOWN",
            "COMMAND_BASE",
            "COMMAND_LOADPEOPLE",
            "RESPONSE_PING",
            "RESPONSE_GENERAL",
            "RESPONSE_TIMINGS_PEOPLE",
            "RESPONSE_TIMINGS_CLICKER"
          ]
        },
        "Timings": {
          "type": [
            "array",
            "null"
          ],
          "items": {
            "type": [
              "object",
              "null"
            ],
            "properties": {
              "PersonID": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "EventTimeMillis": {
                "type": "integer"
              }
            },
            "required": [
              "PersonID",
              "EventTimeMillis"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "MessageType",
        "Timings"
      ]
    },
    "ResponseTimingsClicker": {
      "type": [
        "object",
        "null"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "MessageType": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "UNKNOWN",
            "COMMAND_BASE",
            "COMMAND_LOADPEOPLE",
            "RESPONSE_PING",
            "RESPONSE_GENERAL",
            "RESPONSE_TIMINGS_PEOPLE",
            "RESPONSE_TIMINGS_CLICKER"
          ]
        },
        "Timings": {
          "type": [
            "array",
            "null"
          ],
          "items": {
            "type": "integer"
          }
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "MessageType",
        "Timings"
      ]
    },
    "DummyMessage": {
      "type": [
        "object",
        "null"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "MessageType": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "UNKNOWN",
            "COMMAND_BASE",
            "COMMAND_LOADPEOPLE",
            "RESPONSE_PING",
            "RESPONSE_GENERAL",
            "RESPONSE_TIMINGS_PEOPLE",
            "RESPONSE_TIMINGS_CLICKER"
          ]
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "MessageType"
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "eCommandType",
    "eMessageType",
    "CommandBase",
    "CommandLoadPeople",
    "ResponsePing",
    "ResponseGeneral",
    "ResponseTimingsPeople",
    "ResponseTimingsClicker",
    "DummyMessage"
  ]
}
```

Comment: [JSON](http://json.org/) itself doesn't support enum types. So you won't be able to recreate the data based on the schema. But, if you mirror your C# classes in Java, then you should be able to deserialize the data into them.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Yeah, fixing the generated POJOs by hand does get it working- including the enums- though probably didn't take much less time than just writing them from scratch since I hit an inheritance problem as well that I hadn't noticed.